# Display Notifications across a network in C#

Tags: c#, networking, notifications, message

We have a local network and a program running on each machine which communicates with a database.
I wanted to display notifications (like BalloonTip) across the network to every computer whenever something is changed in the database.
Because everyone is using the same operating system (Windows 10) I could use built in notification controls.

I wanted to do this programmatically in C#.
Do you guys have any ideas how to send a message from one computer to every single one in the network?

Comment: Yeah, look at TCP listeners and servers.

Comment: If you are using SQL server you can create event notification and SQLDependency class to capture the DB events. Once you get the notification, using C# (in client side program) you can raise the Windows notification.